# SerializableFunction equivalent for the DoFn's @Setup

Tags: java, apache-beam, avro

I am using Apache Avro v1.11.0 to auto-generate classes upon a given schema, and I am running an Apache Beam (v2.51.0) pipeline. Let's say the name of the auto-generated class is `Foo`.

So I have a `Foo.Builder` as a property of class `Bar` in an Apache Beam pipeline. Everything is working fine when `Bar` is used inside a `DoFn`, initialized in the DoFn's [`@Setup`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.Setup.html) function. But when I am using `SerializableFunction` instead (or `ProcessFunction`, both used with `MapElements`), and `Bar` is initialized as a property (`private Bar bar = new Bar();`), I am getting a `NotSerializableException` with this error message:

`java.io.NotSerializableException: com.my_project.avro.outgoing_data.Foo$Builder`

I would really prefer using `MapElements` with `SerializableFunction` instead of `ParDo` and `DoFn`.

Is there a `SerializableFunction` equivalent for the DoFn's `@Setup`? Or other suggestions to get it serialized?

Full error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to serialize DoFnWithExecutionInformation{doFn=org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$MapWithFailures$2@536b71b4, mainOutputTag=Tag<org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$MapWithFailures$MapWithFailuresDoFn$1.<init>:398#2249e1908bcf01f3>, sideInputMapping={}, schemaInformation=DoFnSchemaInformation{elementConverters=[], fieldAccessDescriptor=*}}
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:59)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.translateDoFn(ParDoTranslation.java:748)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation$1.translateDoFn(ParDoTranslation.java:268)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.payloadForParDoLike(ParDoTranslation.java:888)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.translateParDo(ParDoTranslation.java:264)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.translateParDo(ParDoTranslation.java:225)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation$ParDoTranslator.translate(ParDoTranslation.java:191)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.PTransformTranslation.toProto(PTransformTranslation.java:250)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.getParDoPayload(ParDoTranslation.java:799)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.isSplittable(ParDoTranslation.java:814)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.PTransformMatchers$6.matches(PTransformMatchers.java:274)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$2.visitPrimitiveTransform(Pipeline.java:288)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:593)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$500(TransformHierarchy.java:240)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:214)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:466)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.replace(Pipeline.java:266)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.replaceAll(Pipeline.java:216)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.performRewrites(DirectRunner.java:254)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:175)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:67)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:321)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:307)
    at com.my_project.dataflow.templates.PubsubToPubsub.run(PubsubToPubsub.java:113)
    at com.my_project.dataflow.templates.PubsubToPubsub.main(PubsubToPubsub.java:86)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.my_project.avro.outgoing_data.Foo$Builder
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:55)
    ... 26 more
```

### I have tried:

1. Doing this casting, when initializing `Foo.Builder` in `Bar`: `Foo.Builder builder = (Foo.Builder & Serializable) Foo.newBuilder()`. But I get an error since `Foo.Builder` cannot be cast to Serializable.
2. In the `SerializableFunction` class, initiate `Bar` in the class constructor, but got the same `NotSerializableException`.
3. Initiate the `Bar` object as a static member of the `SerializableFunction` class. That was successful, but then I realized that I want it as a property.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, Are you using Apache beam with Google Cloud DataFlow ?

Comment: Hi @DhirajSingh, eventually yes, but the error I get is when I run it on my local machine - Mac M1.